# Where should i place the code to observe internet connection so that the user is notified if the device is online or offline?

Tags: kotlin, internet-connection

I have the code to monitor if internet is available. It returns a LiveData and it is observed in the MainActivity . The code is given below.

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)

        NetworkStatusHelper(this@MainActivity).observe(this, Observer {
            when(it){
                NetworkStatus.Available-> Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Back online", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                NetworkStatus.Unavailable-> Snackbar.make(binding.root, "No Internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })
    }
```

NetworkHelper

```
package com.todo.utils.networkhelper

import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Network
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.net.NetworkRequest
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.net.Socket

class NetworkStatusHelper(private val context: Context): LiveData<NetworkStatus>() {

    var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    private lateinit var connectivityManagerCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
    val validNetworkConnections: ArrayList<Network> = ArrayList()


    fun getConnectivityCallbacks() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {


            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {

                super.onAvailable(network)
                val networkCapability =
                    connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                val hasNetworkConnection =
                    networkCapability?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                        ?: false

                if (hasNetworkConnection) {
                    determineInternetAccess(network)
                }
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                super.onLost(network)
                validNetworkConnections.remove(network)
                announceNetworkStatus()
            }

//            override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
//                network: Network,
//                networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
//            ) {
//                super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
//
//                Log.d("validNetworkConnection","onCapabilitiesChanged size "+validNetworkConnections.size)
//
//
//                if (networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)) {
//                   determineInternetAccess(network)
//                } else {
//                    validNetworkConnections.remove(network)
//                }
//                announceNetworkStatus()
//            }

            private fun determineInternetAccess(network: Network) {
                
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    if (InternetAvailability.check()) {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            validNetworkConnections.add(network)
                            
                            announceNetworkStatus()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            fun announceNetworkStatus() {
                
                if (validNetworkConnections.isNotEmpty()) {
                    postValue(NetworkStatus.Available)
                } else {
                    postValue(NetworkStatus.Unavailable)
                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < LOLLIPOP")
    }


    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        connectivityManagerCallback = getConnectivityCallbacks()
        val networkRequest = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            NetworkRequest
                .Builder()
                .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                .build()
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < LOLLIPOP")
        }
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, connectivityManagerCallback)
    }


    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(connectivityManagerCallback)
        }
    }

    object InternetAvailability {

        fun check() : Boolean {
            return try {
                val socket = Socket()
                socket.connect(InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8",53))
                socket.close()
                true
            } catch ( e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
                false
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is here is , the Snackbar is displayed even when the app is opened for the first time .I don't want the Snackbar to be displayed when the app is opened for the first time when network is available. If network is unavailable, then the Snackbar should be displayed even when the app is opened for the first time.

Can someone help to improve the code with correct logic to implement the same.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the LiveData? I suggest handling it on that end.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have added the code now

Comment: That's more complicated than I expected. I was expecting some functions in a ViewModel that populate a MutableLiveData, instead of a LiveData subclass. I was going to suggest exposing a Flow, so the consumer in the Activity could use `dropWhile` to easily get the desired behavior. You will probably need to use a ViewModel, because otherwise, the state of whether it's ever been disconnected will be lost after a configuration change (screen rotation).

Comment: @Tenfour04 Is it advisable to move the whole functionalities in the NetworkHelper class to MainActivity ViewModel class?

Comment: No, I think it is prudent to keep it confined to it's own file or class, but it should be exposed through a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

If your helper class is a Flow, then you can use Flow operators to easily customize its behavior. You should keep the instance of your helper class in a ViewModel so it can maintain its state when there are configuration changes.

Here's a Flow version of your class's functionality. I actually just made it into a function, because I think that's simpler.

I removed the `List<Network>` but you can add it back in if you think it's necessary. I don't think it makes sense to keep a List that can only ever hold at most one item. A device cannot have multiple simultaneous network connections. If you do need it, it won't work for pre-Lollipop, so you will have to juggle differing functionality and probably do need a class instead of just a function.

I think you can probably remove the `checkAvailability()` function as it is redundant, but I put it in because you have it.

I added a pre-Lollipop version based on a broadcast receiver, since you seem to want to add support for that.

```
@get:RequiresPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
val Context.networkStatus: Flow<NetworkStatus> get() = when {
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP -> getNetworkStatusLollipop(this)
    else -> getNetworkStatusPreLollipop(this)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@RequiresPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
private fun getNetworkStatusLollipop(context: Context): Flow<NetworkStatus> = callbackFlow {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        private var availabilityCheckJob: Job? = null

        override fun onUnavailable() {
            availabilityCheckJob?.cancel()
            trySend(NetworkStatus.Unavailable)
        }

        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            availabilityCheckJob = launch {
                send(if(checkAvailability()) NetworkStatus.Available else NetworkStatus.Unavailable)
            }
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            availabilityCheckJob?.cancel()
            trySend(NetworkStatus.Unavailable)
        }
    }

    val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .build()
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, callback)

    awaitClose { connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback) }
}

@RequiresPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
private fun getNetworkStatusPreLollipop(context: Context): Flow<NetworkStatus> = callbackFlow {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            launch {
                if (connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true) {
                    send(if(checkAvailability()) NetworkStatus.Available else NetworkStatus.Unavailable)
                } else {
                    send(NetworkStatus.Unavailable)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))

    awaitClose { context.unregisterReceiver(receiver) }
}

private suspend fun checkAvailability() : Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        Socket().use {
            it.connect(InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53))
        }
        true
    } catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
        false
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewModel, you can use Flow operators to easily expose a Flow that skips initial `NetworkStatus.Available` values:

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val changedNetworkStatus = application.context.networkStatus
        .dropWhile { it == NetworkStatus.Available } // ignore initial available status
        .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, 1) // or .asLiveData() if preferred
}
```

Comment: trySend is showing error.Its not getting detected. Can I use offer instead? I am sorry ,I dont have much idea about Flows

Comment: You might be missing an import. This compiled fine for me. `offer` is deprecated.

Comment: Also I am not getting networkStatus variable in ViewModel class

Comment: It doesn't trigger for the first time if the internet is already disconnected @Tenfour04